# How to add datepicker in MVC without jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datepicker

How to add datepicker in MVC without jQuery

Answer (score 2):

There's no built in Datepicker in MVC. The nearest to a built-in datepicker would be the HTML 5 datetime input type

```
<input type="datetime " value="" />
```

which may show a datepicker in certain browsers, but **[this may not be supported across all your target browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=forms)** and is limited to how you can style it.

In light of this, you may want to look at a JavaScript based datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can no, although when running in Chrome it will allow you to pick dates using a datepicker